# SQL Getting most recent comment in a log

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the most recent note(comment) of a log in sql

Here is my query and what it returns:

```
    SELECT        Project.SupportLogNote.SupportLogID_SupportLogID, Project.SupportLogNote.Note, CAST(Project.SupportLogNote.NoteDate AS Date) AS NoteDate, Project.SupportLogNote.ContactID_CreatorID, 
                         sop.bb_contacts.firstName + ' ' + sop.bb_contacts.lastName AS fullName, Project.SupportLogNote.clientId, Project.SupportLog.StatusID_StatusID
FROM            Project.SupportLogNote INNER JOIN
                         sop.bb_contacts ON Project.SupportLogNote.ContactID_CreatorID = sop.bb_contacts.id INNER JOIN
                         Project.SupportLog ON Project.SupportLogNote.SupportLogID_SupportLogID = Project.SupportLog.SupportLogID
WHERE        (Project.SupportLogNote.ContactID_CreatorID = 109)
ORDER BY Project.SupportLogNote.SupportLogID_SupportLogID DESC
```

[image]

I want to get the most recent Note from the Log so there is only 1 SupportLogID and the most recent note corresponding to that ID.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: which version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: If there are two notes for the same log at the same time, which note do you want ?

Comment: @JBdev The most recent one using the note date. the notes are more of comments on the projects, for example, with notes on the log 21598, i want to get the note that has the most recent date and not show the rest

Comment: What if they both have the same date?

Comment: im using a cast statement to narrow it down, otherwise they are down to the second, the full date and time is there, it just isnt being displayed

Comment: If the column is datetime, you can simply order by that column to get the most recent note. Why order by the ID?

Comment: because it still gets upwards of 1000 rows, it just sorts it differently, i just want to select the most recent note

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines should get you close. Please notice how I used aliases here. It removed tons of code and makes this wall of text into something far more manageable. Also, three part naming in the list of columns has been deprecated. They are going to force you to use aliases at some point.

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT sln.SupportLogID_SupportLogID
        , sln.Note
        , CAST(sln.NoteDate AS Date) AS NoteDate
        , sln.ContactID_CreatorID
        , c.firstName + ' ' + c.lastName AS fullName
        , sln.clientId
        , sl.StatusID_StatusID
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by sl.SupportLogID order by sln.NoteDate desc) as RowNum
    FROM Project.SupportLogNote sln
    INNER JOIN sop.bb_contacts c ON sln.ContactID_CreatorID = c.id 
    INNER JOIN Project.SupportLog sl ON sln.SupportLogID_SupportLogID = sl.SupportLogID
    WHERE sln.ContactID_CreatorID = 109
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY x.SupportLogID_SupportLogID DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using the **WITH TIES** in concert with **Row_Number()**

```
SELECT   Top 1 with ties
         Project.SupportLogNote.SupportLogID_SupportLogID
       , Project.SupportLogNote.Note
       , CAST(Project.SupportLogNote.NoteDate AS Date) AS NoteDate
       , Project.SupportLogNote.ContactID_CreatorID
       , sop.bb_contacts.firstName + ' ' + sop.bb_contacts.lastName AS fullName
       , Project.SupportLogNote.clientId
       , Project.SupportLog.StatusID_StatusID
FROM     Project.SupportLogNote 
INNER JOIN sop.bb_contacts ON Project.SupportLogNote.ContactID_CreatorID = sop.bb_contacts.id 
INNER JOIN Project.SupportLog ON Project.SupportLogNote.SupportLogID_SupportLogID = Project.SupportLog.SupportLogID
WHERE   (Project.SupportLogNote.ContactID_CreatorID = 109)
ORDER BY Row_Number() over (Partition By SupportLogID Order By NoteDate Desc)
```

Comment: @kieronoates  Had little doubt  :)

Comment: @kieronoates What I like about the WITH TIES approach is there is no extra field RowNum or the need for a second SELECT.

Comment: i have never used it before personally but i will keep it in mind for future projects thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think `cross apply` might be a simple way to do this:

```
SELECT sln.SupportLogID_SupportLogID, sln.Note, CAST(sln.NoteDate AS Date) AS NoteDate,
       sln.ContactID_CreatorID, 
       c.firstName + ' ' + sop.bb_contacts.lastName AS fullName, sln.clientId, sl.StatusID_StatusID
FROM  Project.SupportLogNote sln INNER JOIN
      sop.bb_contacts c
      ON sln.ContactID_CreatorID = c.id CROSS APPLY
      (SELECT TOP 1 sl.*
       FROM p.SupportLog sl
       WHERE sln.SupportLogID_SupportLogID =sl.SupportLogID
       ORDER BY sl.NoteDate DESC
      ) sl
WHERE sln.ContactID_CreatorID = 109
ORDER BY sln.SupportLogID_SupportLogID DESC;
```